# Do we want accepted answers to be pinned to the top?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

##### Stack Exchange staff have [announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers) an upcoming change to the way answer acceptance works.

Currently, the original poster of a question can accept one non-deleted answer. This does several things,

- the question poster receives 2 rep, and the answer poster receives 15 rep
- the answer has an added green tick mark below its score and vote buttons
- the answer itself is pinned to the top of the list of answers, regardless of sort variable

This change will affect the last of these behaviours, removing the "pin to top". Staff have indicated this may be configurable per site - each individual site can have this behaviour turned off or left on (with the default setting yet to be determined by consensus and research).

##### Please indicate by voting on the answers below, which setting you would prefer.

Downvotes will be ignored for this purpose, as they add no useful information. Just upvote one, or both or neither.

Comment: This question and its answers were derived from the template created by Nij on [Sports.SE](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1027), via [Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/34513), via [Earth Science.SE](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1932/14117).

Answer (score 1):

#### Remove the "pin to top" behaviour.

I want this behaviour to be removed. An accepted answer should be sorted in the same way as all answers.

Answer (score 1):

#### Keep the "pin to top" behaviour.

I want this behaviour to be kept. An accepted answer should be placed at the top of the list.